# Improving the performance of aggregating the value of a key spread across multiple JSON rows

Tags: json, scala, elasticsearch, redis, cassandra

I'm currently storing the data in the following format (JSON) in a Redis ZSET. The score is the timestamp in miliseconds.

```
 <timestamp_1> -   [ { "key1" : 200 }, { "key2": 100 }, {"key3" : 5 }, .... {"key_n" : 1} ]
 <timestamp_2> -   [ { "key50" : 500 }, { "key2": 300 }, {"key3" : 290 },  ....{"key_m" : 26} ]
 ....
 ....
 <timestamp_k> -   [ { "key1" : 100 }, { "key2": 200 }, {"key3" : 50 },  ....{"key_p" : 150} ]
```

I want to extract the values for a key between a given time range.

For example, the values of key2 will in the above example for the entire time range would be.

```
[timestamp_1:100, timestamp_2:300, ..... timestamp_k:200]
```

I can get the current output but I've to parse the JSON for each row and then iterate through it to get the value of a given key in each row. The parsing becomes a bottleneck as the size of each row increases (n,m, and p can be as big as 10000).

I'm looking for suggestions about if there is a way to improve the performance in Redis? Are there any specific parsers (in Scala) that can help here.

I'm also open to using other stores such as Cassandra and Elasticsearch if they give better performance. I'm also open to other formats apart from JSON to store the data in Redis ZSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cassandra** will work just fine for your requirement.

You can keep `key_id` as the partitioning key and `timestamp` as the row key.

You always define your query before designing your column family in cassandra. *extract the values for a key between a given time range.*

If you are using CQL3,

Create schema:

`CREATE TABLE imp_keys (key_id text, score int, timestamp timeuuid,PRIMARY KEY(key_id,timestamp));`

Access data:

`SELECT score FROM imp_keys WHERE key_id=key2 AND timestamp > maxTimeuuid(start_date) AND timestamp < maxTimeuuid(end_date);`